# Run the second scenario only if the first one passes in JBehave

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am using JBehave with selenium and serenity and I have 3 scenarios.  I want to run the scenarios one by one. If the scenario one passes then run the second scenario. If scenario two passes then run the third scenario. If scenario one fails then it should not run any other scenarios. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenarios should be independent of each other and be a complete representation of one objective in one situation.  Chaining scenarios together in BDD is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

The next question is why are you applying a fail fast strategy for functional testing.  This needs to be reconsidered to determine if that a well founded approach for your situation.  While fail fast is the norm for a deployment pipeline it is not a good approach for automated functional testing in general and particularly during feature driven development with BDD.  It is general a better approach to purse a fail safe strategy for automated functional testing.  I advise that you run all tests to completion.  This will typically provide more value.  It will avoid an early failing test from masking potentially more serious failing tests or tests against more important or valuable features.  A comprehensive test report allows rectification work to be prioritised.

If the trigger of failure for all three scenarios is common, then use a common pre-conditional step. e.g. `Given the customer is authorised`.  Then simply guard each scenario with that pre-condition.

If the trigger for a failure is environmental then use a bell weather test in your runner or using the appropriate @Before test hook.  e.g. LDAP or database being available.  Then test this Assumption using each feature or scenario.

If none of these apply you will need to elaborate your requirement with some examples of the scenarios you are using.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Actually that have to be only one scenario but that is a big scenario. so i thought i could split it. Now i realized the scenario should be independent. Now i am writing one big scenario. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use compromised exceptions, but JBehave (and BDD scenarios in general) are really not intended to be used that way - each scenario should be independent.

Comment: Thanks John. Now i realized Scenario should be independent.